# how to call files as resources in Dev c++ bloodshed

Tags: deadlock, dev-c++, bankers-algorithm

The project ask to call 3 separate files in this project for the bankers algorithm one is called a driver

## include "banker.c"

## include "process.c"

Comment: I must assume that this is only part of your post, because it does not make any sense at all to me.

Comment: the driver is the main file, and it uses resources from both the banker.c file and process.c file, the project focuses on using the bankers algorithm. I've been triyng to post the code but keep having issues posting it.